# Making a facebook program

Tags: facebook

I read that to make a facebook program you have to have a server. Is that true? I'm planning on making a facebook program but am wondering what kind of hassle it is.

Comment: Well, what are you making? If it is a desktop client, then no, you don't.

Comment: I'm making an iPhone program that interfaces with Facebook.

Comment: The answer on the bottom then is completely relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook just released integration with Heroku so that you can make an app without having to manage your own server. The post about it is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558/).